# Android Studio Cannot Reach ADB Server/Error while waiting for device: is already running/Waiting for target devices to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I just cannot run my application on the Android Studio emulator. I've tried every possbile solution from the internet, as well as reinstalling the Android Studio. I have couple of issues:

1. Cannot reach ADB Server, attempting to reconnect - I've tried everything from the internet to solve the issue, but it is still displaying every single time
2. Error while waiting for device: is already running - I get this error, when the emulator is running (when I run the device directly from the Device Manager) and I try to run the application on the emulator.
3. Waiting for target devices to come online - I get this error, when I try to run the application without previously running the emulator from the device manager. This waiting is infinitely and after 300s the process get timed out.

I am hopeless, I think like I tried every single possible solution to these problems and my application still do not run. I've tried reinstalling emulators and tried various of them. Any suggestions what I could try?

I am using Windows 10 on my computer.

Comment: @Robert you are right, I've added the OS - Windows

Comment: Open your Windows Taskmanager and on the details tab check for existing adb processes. If there are adb processes kill them all and restart adb by executing `adb start-server`

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. It "only" happens when Docker is running and while using a VPN (or some combination of both).

Answer (score 0):

Selecting File -> Repair IDE worked for me.

[image]